# SpringBoot 3.1.2 Upgrade (from 3.0.6) - Existing Unidirectional @OneToOne mapping no longer works. (hibernate.PropertyAccessException)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

### **Problem:**

I am currently upgrading an API from `SpringBoot 3.0.6` to `SpringBoot 3.1.2`. Internally, Hibernate also gets updated from `6.1.7.Final` to `6.2.6.Final`.

With this minor version update, existing @OneToOne mappings break when calling the `RecordDao` because it is unable to infer the correct types between the 2 child entities that is defined in the `Record` entity.

`Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set value of type [com.hidden.CurrentRole] : 'com.hidden.Record.futureRole' (setter)`

### **Existing Code:**

I have a parent entity where 2 child entities inherits the parent's id using the JOINED inheritance strategy. `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)`

And ultimately, a separate entity that associates the 2 child classes using a @OneToOne mapping.

**Parent:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RESOURCE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "RESOURCE_TYPE_CD", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, columnDefinition = "INT")
abstract class Resource(

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "RESOURCE_ID_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "RESOURCE_ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "RESOURCE_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    override var id: Long? = null,

    @Column(name = "RESOURCE_TYPE_CD", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    open var resourceType: ResourceType

): MutableAuditableBaseJpa<Long>()
```

**Child Entities:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RESOURCE_FUTURE_ROLE")
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
class FutureRole(
    ...
): Resource(null, ResourceType.FUTURE_ROLE)
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RESOURCE_CURRENT_ROLE")
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
class CurrentRole(
    ...
): Resource(null, ResourceType.CURRENT_ROLE)
```

**Record entity & dao where child association exists**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RECORD")
open class Record(

    @Column(name = "RESOURCE_ID") override var resourceId: Long,
    ...
): MutableAuditableBaseJpa<Long>() {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RESOURCE_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    open var futureRole: FutureRole? = null

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "RESOURCE_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    open var employee: CurrentRole? = null
}
```

```
interface RecordDao: JpaRepository<Record, Long> {
    fun findByResourceId(resourceId: Long): Record?
}
```

I have tried updating the @OneToOne child associations to a @ManyToOne.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name = "RESOURCE_FUTURE_ROLE", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)], inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)])
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
open var futureRole: FutureRole? = null

@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name = "RESOURCE_CURRENT_ROLE", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)], inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)])
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
open var employee: CurrentRole? = null
```

With this update, I do see resources being returned but when deployed, all the data was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug within Hibernate version `6.2.6.Final`. Will be resolved in `6.2.8`+

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16934